# Слушатель клавиатуры для JTextArea

Tags: java, textarea, listener

Задача: добавить слушателя клавиатуры для поля JTextArea. 
Текст части кода:

```
    public class ExerciseGUI extends JInternalFrame {

    ...
    private JTextArea reference_text_area;
    private JTextArea entry_text_area;
    ...

    ...

    public void reveal (Lessons lessons) {
        adjusted = 0;
        this.lessons = lessons; 
        title_label.setText(lessons.get_title());
        descr_label.setText(lessons.get_instructions());
        reference_text_area.setText(lessons.get_text());
        entry_text_area.setText("");

        cursor = 0;
        progress = 0;
    }

    ...
    private void show_typing_cursor()  {
        // весь блок в try catch (Exception e)
        reference_text_area.setCaretPosition(cursor);
        reference_text_area.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights(); // ochistka podcvetki
        try {
            reference_text_area.getHighlighter().addHighlight(cursor, cursor + 1, painter);
        } catch (BadLocationException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }

    private void handle_key_press (char char_struck)   { 

        handle_key_press_lesson(char_struck);
        if (progress == reference_text_area.getText().length()) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Youy accuracy is" + (reference_text_area.getText().length()), "Information", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    }

    private void handle_key_press_lesson(char char_struck)  {  
        if (progress < reference_text_area.getText().length()) {
            char char_wanted = reference_text_area.getText().charAt(progress);
        if (char_struck == char_wanted) {
            adjusted ++;
            entry_text_area.append(reference_text_area.getText().substring(progress, progress + 1));
        progress++; 
        cursor++;
        update_status(true);
        } 

        else {
            entry_text_area.append("*");
        }
        progress++;
        cursor++;
        update_status(false);
               }
        entry_text_area.setCaretPosition(cursor + 1);
        show_typing_cursor();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExerciseGUI frame = new ExerciseGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public ExerciseGUI() {

        //неверные данные массива   
        reference_text_area.addKeyListener(this.getKeyListeners()[0]);
        entry_text_area.addKeyListener(this.getKeyListeners()[0]);
        ...

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
            private void formKeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                if (! evt.isControlDown()) {
                    char key_pressed = evt.getKeyChar();
                    int keycode = evt.getKeyCode();
                    handle_key_press(key_pressed);
                    evt.consume();
                }

            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){
                formKeyReleased(evt);
            }
            private void formKeyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt){
                formKeyTyped(evt);
            }
            private void formKeyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
                if((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)||(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)||(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)||(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                    entry_text_area.setCaretPosition(cursor);
                }

            }
        });

        setResizable(true);
        ...

        reference_text_area = new JTextArea();
        reference_text_area.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        reference_text_area.setEditable(false);
        reference_text_area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        reference_text_area.setLineWrap(true);
        dril_pane.setLeftComponent(reference_text_area);

        //JTextArea entry_text_area = new JTextArea();
        entry_text_area = new JTextArea();
        entry_text_area.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        entry_text_area.setEditable(false);
        entry_text_area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        entry_text_area.setLineWrap(true);
        dril_pane.setRightComponent(entry_text_area);

        ...
    }

}
```

было предложено добавить слушателей таким способом

> reference_text_area.addKeyListener(this.getKeyListeners()[0]);
>   entry_text_area.addKeyListener(this.getKeyListeners()[0]);

Но  Eclipse при запуске программы выдает

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0   at
>   ExerciseGUI.(ExerciseGUI.java:125)  at
>   MainWindow.(MainWindow.java:80)     at
>   MainWindow$1.run(MainWindow.java:55)  at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Если пользоваться таким способом:

> entry_text_area.addKeyListener(this.getKeyListeners()[0]);
>   то какие параметры вписать в [массив]

если пользоваться другим способом подключения слушателей, подскажите как ещё их можно подключить... 
Благодарю.

Comment: чтобы взять из коллекции что-нибудь ненужное, надо сначала положить в коллекцию что-нибудь ненужное. А у вас наоборот все.

Comment: поясните Ваш ответ поподробнее пожалуйста, что именно не хватает в коде для полного счастья или что с чем поменять?